# How to upload a HTML variable to a PHP file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

On my website I am trying to basically generate a random code (which I will set up later) and then pass that code into a PHP file to later retrieve it when the client needs it. But my code just isn't working.

**Here is the code:**

Javascript/HTML:

```
function init() {    
    var code = "12345";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'codes.php',
            data: { code: code},
            success: function(response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
 <?php 
     $code = $_POST['code'];
     echo $code
 ?>
```

So what I understand that is supposed to happen is that the code is uploaded or 'posted' to the php file and then the #result is the echo $code. None of that happens and I have no idea.

Comment: Are you actually calling the `init()` function anywhere in your javascript? You've declared it but it needs to be called to run. Also, you're missing a semicolon after the `echo $code`

Comment: yes its called at the end of the html code. I didnt include it because it just has unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your code working perfect with some basic changes.
You need a html element with id 'result'.
And then you need to call your init() as per requirement.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
function init() {    
    var code = "12345";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'codes.php',
            data: { code: code},
            success: function(response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my server in the head of my document, and it worked :)
I used on complete instead of on success.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function init() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "codes.php",
        data: {  
                'code': '12345'
            },

        complete: function(data){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data.responseText
        },
    });
}
init();
</script>
```

with codes.php the same as you have :)

Comment: I assume you are using php json_decode() in the php handler? You may want to show that so he knows to decode the data, and encode the response, as the dataType in this example is json (javascript object notation)

Comment: Nope, in his example he was just sending a string over, which the dataType wouldn't have affected.  It was an ajax I copied over anyways,  but if it makes you feel better, I took it out.

Comment: I just figure the less confusion the better the answer is, especially when a user is new to the subject they are looking into.

Answer (score 0):

just a few notes:

1. Make sure you point your url to the correct file. You can check it by using the console network. Or you can simply print anything out, not just the $_POST data. e.g:

   ```
   echo 'Test info';
   ```
2. Open browser developer panel, to see if is there any client code issue. For example, document with id 'result' existed, or you have not included jquery in. The developer console will tell you everything on the client side. For Chrome, check it out here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
3. Have you actually called init() ?